# How to split a string into an array

Tags: templating, filter

How can I split (or explode) a Twig string like this:

```
{% set fruits = "Apples; Bananas; Tomatoes" %}
```

into an array like this:

```
{{ ["Apples", "Bananas", "Tomatoes"] }}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the [`split`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html) filter.

```
{% set fruits = "Apples; Bananas; Tomatoes" | split('; ') %}
```

Comment: Strange why it is shown that my question was viewed only 1 Time...

Comment: Of course fruits is MUCH more better and accurately then items. I had some doubts but now in 5 mins I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Twig's split filter.](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html)

```
{{ "Apples; Bananas; Tomatoes"|split('; ') }}
```